# SQL: NOT LIKE still pulling unwanted data from column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to run a simple query that will pull results that **don't** pertain certain data from a specific column. When i run the query, there are no errors, but the query ignores the NOT LIKE:

```
SELECT RemoteAddress, Username, RemotePath, LocalPath, ResultID
FROM dbo.tbl_ClientOperations
WHERE Time_stamp between '2020-06-21 00:00:01.000' AND '2020-06-22 15:00:00.001'
  AND LocalPath NOT LIKE '*\Prod\*'
  AND ResultID = '0';
```

I also tried using NOT IN ('*\PROD*') but same results. Its giving me rows where the LocalPath has \Prod\ in it

Comment: could you please show some data, so that we can check your query see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: with the `dbo.tbl_` and the camelCase column names, this looks more like SQL Server than MySQL.  Note that asterisk character is a literal character i.e. not a wild card in the the LIKE operator; to match zero one or more characters, we use `%` wildcard character.

Comment: in sql server too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `not like` is strange.  I am guessing you want:

```
LocalPath NOT LIKE '%Prod%'
```

This returns any `LocalPath` that does not have `Prod` in it.

Also, if `LocalPath` can be `NULL`, you need to take that into account separately:

```
(LocalPath NOT LIKE '%Prod%' OR LocalPath IS NULL)
```